# Mechanics question using a differential equation

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I have come across a question on a first-year undergraduate mechanics paper:

[image]

I am unsure of how I should approach this. How can I use the radius to create a link between this and the speed of the hailstone? Especially since air resistance is being neglected, why is the radius still important in the question since no matter how big the radius is, the surface area doesn't create any further drag?

My initial thoughts would be to calculate a time using the differential equation except I am unsure what to consider in order to find such a value. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: well radius would still matter ,because the size and mass of the hailstone depend on it.

Comment: When air resistance is neglected no terminal velocity, it falls with exponentially increasing radius with time.

Comment: Didn't Galilieo show and Newton deduce that the dynamics of free fall with no air resistance is independent of the mass of the object, and has no limiting velocity (in theory)? Are you sure you have the full question quoted correctly? Consider asking this on physics stackexchange.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question and sufficiently mathematical to grace these pages. Please don't close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass of the spherical hailstone is $$m=\frac 43\pi r^3\rho$$ where$\rho$ is the density.
So $$\frac{dm}{dt}=4\pi r^2\rho \frac{dr}{dt}=3mk$$

Meanwhile the equation of motion is $$\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=mg$$
$$\implies m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}=mg$$

For the limiting speed we require $\frac{dv}{dt}\rightarrow0$

In which case, $$v(3mk)\rightarrow mg$$

So the terminal velocity is $\frac{g}{3k}$

Comment: I can follow the mathematics here but the physics confuses me. If the water(vapor) condensing on the hailstone were falling alongside then the fact that they joined up wouldn't matter. So the underlying assumption must be that the vapor isn't falling until it condenses on the hailstone. If that's happening then there's significant interaction between the stone and the medium, so neglecting air resistance seems to make no modeling sense to me. I wonder what a physicist would say.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think there is a difference between air resistance, on the one hand, and resistance due to the particles of water vapour, on the other hand, which is largely accounted for by the modelling of the condensation as described.

Comment: @EthanBolker Of course this model has its limitations. Air resistance can be neglected if the falling object's plane area is small (for example when $t$ is small enough and the hailstone is being formed). For small $t$ the change in mass dominates the air friction and this model can be applied. When the hailstone is big enough, the drag force must be considered (as well as the mass increasing). This can be shown by nondimensional analysis. It is a pitty that in this forum nobody let people think and completely solve the asked question...

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the equation you are solving is:

$$f=mg=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)$$ with $$m=m(t)$$